# How to set the express session, it is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-session

"express-session" it's installed...
The errors are shown in the image...(https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YElD.png)...

```
// app.js file 
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');   //<---
const partials = require('express-partials');
.
.
const app = express();
.
.

const middleware = [   //<---
  partials(), // allows layouts
  .
  .

  session ({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY, // Set a secret key for securely signing the session ID cookie
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: store
  }),

];
```

Need to set the session...

Answer (score 1):

First thought: I can't see in your file invoking `express` you have installed and put as required:

```
const app = express()
```

and next

```
  app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SECRET_KEY, 
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        store: store,
    })
);
```

Other thing is to make sure where are your modules installed. Can you check where do you have your `node_modules/` directory?

I mean:

```
./node_modules/
```

or maybe

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

`npm install -g express-session` installs **globally**, not locally. Modules are put into  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, and puts executable files go to `/usr/local/bin`.

`npm install express-session` installs **locally**. This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in `./node_modules`, executables go in `./node_modules/.bin/`. And that means the script you are running needs to be run from the same directory containing `node_modules`.